# How do I login as a SYSTEM on a Windows XP computer?

Tags: windows, pstools

I need to login as SYSTEM because my Apache runs a process as a SYSTEM (that's what I see in Task Manager) and I need to run that process from the command-line (psexec.exe) to accept the EULA popup, otherwise it will just hang on the Apache side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot log in interactively as SYSTEM your best bet is to temporarily run Apache under a different account, accept the EULA (obviously for some other package, because Apache doesn't have such a popup), the reset it back to the SYSTEM account.

Answer (score 0):

`psexec -s` will run things as System but interactively on the current desktop.

Comment: No. The -s flag runs the **remote** process as a system account... not the psexec process on my local machine.

Comment: @Luca: Yes. If you want to run multiple commands, use `psexec -s cmd` and have a command shell running as system, from where you can then run arbitrary commands (except Windows Explorer which gets confused about trying to be the shell).

Answer (score 0):

You can have apache accept the EULA by running psexec with the `-accepteula` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OS you use you can use the at command to schedule a job.

First get the local time with the "time" command.

Then schedule a job one minute later from the command line:

C:\Users\wilfriedvs>at 10:01 /interactive cmd.exe

Comment: Have you even read the question? This may be a good answer for something else but certainly not this question.

Comment: Did you try the answer before downvoting?
Commands started with "at" run under the System account.

Comment: +1 - That's a trick I've used since the NT 4.0 days to get a SYSTEM shell. I don't believe it works in Vista or newer Windows OS's, though...

Comment: Vista or later can use "schtasks.exe"
You can still use "at" but the command won't run interactively, I still use it to run vbs scripts as system.